# Automator application that asks me for a YouTube URL before running the command

Tags: macos, command-line, automator

I'm trying to make an Automator application that runs this command:

```
youtube-dl -x --audio-format wav -o "~/Downloads/%(title)s.%(ext)s" 'youtube file url'
```

but I’d like for it to ask me for the YouTube URL before running. Have been unsuccessful so far, would appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: Please add the Automator workflow you already have (screenshot is enough).

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/QdJC8tNx/Automator.jpg

Comment: Through lots of trial and error I finally managed to actually download and extract the audio. However I'm getting an error message: "ffprobe/avprobe and ffmpeg/avconv not found. Please install one." Thing is my ffmpeg is fully up to date. I even reinstalled it just in case. My "youtube-dl" is also up to date.

Answer (score 0):

> Through lots of trial and error I finally managed to actually download and extract the audio. However I'm getting an error message: "ffprobe/avprobe and ffmpeg/avconv not found. Please install one." Thing is my ffmpeg is fully up to date. I even reinstalled it just in case. My "youtube-dl" is also up to date.

Addressing your comment...

The default `PATH` passed to a **Run Shell Script** *action* in **Automator** is:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Add a `PATH` *statement* at the top of the *code* in the **Run Shell Script** *action*,

To determine what the normal `PATH` is, in **Terminal** run `echo $PATH` and then for the **Run Shell Script** *action* use whatever it outputs, e.g.

```bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

for f in "$@"; do
    /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -x --audio-format wav -o "$HOME/Downloads/%(title)s.%(ext)s"  "$f"
done
```

Comment: You're welcome. Quoting the tilde will cause it not to expand -`"~/Downloads.....` . Might be best to use `$HOME` instead.

Comment: @fd0, Yeah, I typically use `$HOME` and I was just trying to copy what the OP was using because I hadn't had any coffee yet :)

Comment: Thanks so much @user3439894, this works perfectly! When I tried running it the first time it gave me some "developer is unidentified" errors for ffmpeg and ffprobe. So I located them, right clicked to open them via Terminal and clicked on the "do you want to open anyway" dialog. I've spent several months trying to get this to work via Google and trial and error, so happy everything finally works now exactly how I want it to :) Thank you @ fd0 too  for all the rewording and reformatting on the original query too!

Comment: I'd now like to convert this Automator app into a Script Editor (AppleScript) app. I tried copying and pasting but the Script Editor was asking me for variables and other stuff. How would I go about doing that?